# Generate public key from private key

Tags: private-key, public-key

When openssl generates a public/private key pair, does it first generate private key and then computes public key from private key ? Or should public key be calculated at the same time of the private key ?

Is it possible to have multiple public keys which match to the same private key?

Thanks

Comment: That depends on the particular crypto system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in RSA at least, in fact, you can have one public key with several "different" private keys. In RSA the step is to generate the public key first, then generate the private key afterward. This is because several randomly chosen values are chosen at the start and before the final private key generation, but they're all discarded after generating the private key. Had they were kept, it's possible to redo the step with different values and still use the same public key, but while the resulting private key will look different at first glance, they're [mathematically equal](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/48829/21310). Even if you use algorithms that might create multiple keys, for all intent and purpose, they're the same key, since it will be impossible to infer if a certain key of a set of private keys is used to sign, only that the key is a valid pair for the public key you have.

Also, this seems to be an X-Y question. Even if you find an algorithm that creates multiple public keys for a single private key, since the public key is meant to be, well, public, there's nothing stopping the public from encrypting the same message and observe the identical encrypted result. So you can't have two secretive actors who don't want to be associated to use those keys. As you mention OpenSSL specifically, on SSL you might give different public keys (assuming such algorithm exist, since as I point out it's the reverse in RSA) to different CA or maybe embed them to different apps/device, but since CAs support a single cert serving multiple domains/server, and multiple CAs serving a single domain, there doesn't seem to be any benefit from the current practice.

Comment: You said the public key is generated first, but look at this procedure: The private key is generated first:  openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 -rand /dev/urandom -out private.txt   && openssl ec -in private.txt -pubout -outform DER|tail -c 65|xxd -p -c 65 > public.txt   So i do not understand...

Comment: That's why I said at least in RSA, which is commonly used for SSL. secp256k1 meanwhile is almost exclusively for BTC. If you want multiple public key so you can have different receipt address, see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/68657/how-can-a-deterministic-wallet-have-one-private-key-but-multiple-public-keys

Comment: So you mean with rsa public key is generated first then private key ? And for secp256k1 it is the opposite : private first and public then ?

Comment: In ECDSA (where secp256k1 is used), the private key is randomly selected, then and only then, the public key can be calculated.